# SQL query homework furstration

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery, pivot-table

I have to recreate this excel sheet:

[image]

With this table:

[image]

The following is what I have right now, but this obviously shows me Set 1 four times.

```
SELECT WEDSTRIJDFORMULIER.*, INDELING.Klas,
  CONCAT(SUM(UITSLAG.PuntenA), ' - ', SUM(UITSLAG.PuntenB)) AS Uitslag,
  CONCAT(UITSLAG.ScoreA, ' - ', UITSLAG.ScoreB) AS 'Set 1',
  CONCAT(UITSLAG.ScoreA, ' - ', UITSLAG.ScoreB) AS 'Set 2',
  CONCAT(UITSLAG.ScoreA, ' - ', UITSLAG.ScoreB) AS 'Set 3',
  CONCAT(UITSLAG.ScoreA, ' - ', UITSLAG.ScoreB) AS 'Set 4'
FROM WEDSTRIJDFORMULIER, INDELING, UITSLAG
WHERE INDELING.Team = WEDSTRIJDFORMULIER.TeamA
  AND UITSLAG.WID = WEDSTRIJDFORMULIER.WID
GROUP BY UITSLAG.WID
```

How can I get the scores from Set 1, 2, 3 and 4 with subquery's? I'm not allowed to use Joins.

Comment: but you're Joining already...

Comment: In your code: `FROM WEDSTRIJDFORMULIER, INDELING, UITSLAG` you are using "old school" pre-1992 SQL joins! a sure way to do bad on any assignment!

Comment: Why on Earth would *anyone* TEACH to use correlated subqueries in preference to joins?!

Comment: Don't ask me. This is actually what they teach us (first year ICT).

Comment: I doubt they're teaching it in preference to joins.  It's probably just an exercise to teach them how to use correlated subqueries.  (Trying to give them the benefit of the doubt.)

Comment: Stupid university professor tricks.

Answer (score 0):

Aside from the comments about JOINs vs WHERE clause ANSI querying, I think the bigger thing you are missing is the fact that "Uitslag" and "Sets" 1-4 are not 5 columns, but 10... each one having two columns for the respective scoreA and scoreB

Uitslag has Excel columns E+F, Set 1 has G+H, Set 2 has I+J, etc.  The fact that someone "prettied the headings" with the labels spanning both columns for looks is masking the answer.

```
SELECT 
      WEDSTRIJDFORMULIER.*, 
      INDELING.Klas,
      SUM(UITSLAG.PuntenA) as UitslagA,
      SUM(UITSLAG.PuntenB) as UitslagB,
      SUM( case when UITSLAG.Set = 1 then UITSLAG.ScoreA else 0 end ) as Set1A,
      SUM( case when UITSLAG.Set = 1 then UITSLAG.ScoreB else 0 end ) as Set1B,
      SUM( case when UITSLAG.Set = 2 then UITSLAG.ScoreA else 0 end ) as Set2A,
      SUM( case when UITSLAG.Set = 2 then UITSLAG.ScoreB else 0 end ) as Set2B,
      SUM( case when UITSLAG.Set = 3 then UITSLAG.ScoreA else 0 end ) as Set3A,
      SUM( case when UITSLAG.Set = 3 then UITSLAG.ScoreB else 0 end ) as Set3B,
      SUM( case when UITSLAG.Set = 4 then UITSLAG.ScoreA else 0 end ) as Set4A,
      SUM( case when UITSLAG.Set = 4 then UITSLAG.ScoreB else 0 end ) as Set4B
   FROM 
      WEDSTRIJDFORMULIER, 
      INDELING, 
      UITSLAG
   WHERE 
          INDELING.Team = WEDSTRIJDFORMULIER.TeamA
      AND UITSLAG.WID = WEDSTRIJDFORMULIER.WID
   GROUP BY 
      UITSLAG.WID
```

Notice the case/when within the SUM() where it is specifically looking for each only when it is the corresponding "SET" for respective 1-4.  If not for the appropriate sum column result, just use 0, otherwise, get the score.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1 - Start aliasing your tables. For instance, UITSLAG A means that you can now say A.Klas instead of UITSLAG.Klas.

Step 2 - as @Dan Andrews and @KM pointed out, you're already using joins. Take those out.

Step 3 - Write a subquery. I'm not going to do one for you as this is homework. But let me walk you through it.

To start a subquery, you open parentheses and then type a complete select statement and close the parentheses. A subquery within a select statement can only return one value...just one!

To use a subquery with no joins, it will need to be a correlated subquery. So, in my main query, I reference table A, whose key is A.Key.

So, to bring back the foreign key from Table B which relates to the Primary Key in Table A, I need to write the following subquery within a select statement:

```
Select A.varA
    , A.varB --your subquery will start next
    , (Select B.Key 
        From TableB as B
        Where A.Key = B.Key) --Notice I referenced TableA without mentioning it in my subquery. This is what makes it a correlated subquery.
From TableA as A;
```

See, in this way, you can reference the tables in the main query within the subquery, thus making Joins unnecessary!

Now, as @Eggyal was pointing out, using correlated subqueries will almost always be slower that using joins. However, there will be times when you can only get what you want through a correlated subquery, so learn it well!!!